# GStreamer add video overlay when recording screen to filesink

Tags: gstreamer

Hello i am recording screen to video file with GStreamer ximagesrc element using QT.
I want to draw circles on mouse clicks locations.
Can someone give a hint how to achieve this, looking at GstVideoOverlay I understand that it is used only on playing video in some window and draw in that window not directly in video stream that could be saved to file. Guessing that GstVideoOverlayRectangle can help here, but i`m not sure...
Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend to look at `cairooverlay`:

https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gst-plugins-good/html/gst-plugins-good-plugins-cairooverlay.html